# How can I voice type :-) using Google speech recognition in French?

Tags: android-12, voice-recognition, google-pixel-6

In English, I can type :-) by voice by saying "smiley". How can I voice type :-) in French? I use Google speech recognition on Pixel 6 + Android 12.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Utiliser l'Assistant Google pour saisir du texte avec votre voix](https://support.google.com/gboard/answer/11197787?hl=fr-FR) (English version [Use Google Assistant to type with your voice](https://support.google.com/gboard/answer/11197787?hl=en-GB)), you must say "Emoji souriant".

> Pour ajouter un emoji, dites le nom de l'emoji, par exemple "Emoji souriant".

English version

> To add an emoji: Say the name of the emoji, like 'Smiley emoji'.